# How to cancel the search in google maps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So basically what the title says. How can I cancel the search when I delete everything inside the search box?

A small description of what it does:

- I have implemented Google Maps in the page
- Added a search box
- Have some markers
- If I type anything in the box and hit *Enter*, markers that do not contain the string in the search box in their title become hidden
- If I change the text inside the search box, markers that contain that string in their titles become visible again, others become hidden

But what I want to add as well(and what doesn't work at the moment) is: **if I remove everything from the search box I want all markers to become visible again**. However, it doesn't work.

Code for handling text change in the search box:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
  alert('input: ' + input.value);
  var newMarkers = []; //a temp variable to store the markers that should be visible
  if ((places.length <= 0) || (input.length <= 0) || (input.value == "") || (input.value == "Search Box")) {
    //here I set all markers to visible again(newMarkers = markers)
  } else {
    //here I push all markers that fit the criteria into the newMarkers variable
  }
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < newMarkers.length; i++) {
    bounds.extend(newMarkers[i].getPosition());
  }
  markerCluster.clearMarkers();
  markerCluster.addMarkers(newMarkers);
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
});
```

The problem is that the code never gets into the first *if*. Actually, it never gets into this *function* at all if I erase whole text in the search box and hit *Enter*.

Comment: when do you trigger the `places_changed` event?  Show us the code responsible... if this function never executes, you must not be triggering it when you should.

Comment: @duncan `places_changed` event is event of Google Maps SearchBox: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#SearchBox

Comment: `This event is fired when the user selects a query,` - if the user doesn't select anything, then you could trigger the event yourself: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#event

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, the SearchBox `places_changed` event *"is fired when the user selects a query"*

If the user deletes the contents then they must not be selecting anything.  Instead you could trigger the event yourself: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#event

```
if (input.value.length === 0) {
  google.maps.event.trigger(searchBox, 'places_changed');
}
```